# Can I use "google-translate" as a verb?

Tags: verbs, neologisms

I wanted to say: "I asked the question in English and received the answer in German. **I don't mind the language because I can easily google-translate it.**"

Can I say it this way? Please advise;)

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

As with many invented words, it would be rather casual. In a formal situation you could avoid the verbed phrase. But in the informal context you give, it would be find.